# Mocking a method's response using SinonJS

Tags: mocha.js, sinon

I am very new to testing world. I have a following function:

```
exports.get = function (para1) {
    var response = querySys(para1);
    response.in = 1;
    return response;
}
```

I want to mock the result of `querySys` method.

I want it to return `{in: 0, out: 1}`.

So how do I do it with Sinon? Do I have to mock it or stub it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stub the response easily:

```
sinon
     .stub(module_name, 'querySys')
     .returns({in: 0, out: 1});
```